# How to workout if a datetime is older than x months in Python

Tags: python, django

I want to find out if a entry has been updated in the last 6 months.

This is what I have tried:

```
 def is_old(self):
        """
        Is older than 6 months (since last update)
        """
        time_threshold = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12)
        if self.last_update < time_threshold:
            return False
        return True
```

but i get the error:

```
    if self.last_update < time_threshold:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `days` keyword

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
datetime.date(2014, 5, 26)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=180)
datetime.date(2013, 12, 27)
>>> datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=6*365/12)
datetime.date(2013, 12, 25)
```

Also, coming to your actual error: `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date`

You can just do

```
def is_old(self):

    time_threshold = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=6*365/12)

    #The following code can be simplified, i shall let you figure that out yourself. 
    if self.last_update and self.last_update.date() < time_threshold:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: perfect. if self.last_update and self.last_update.date() > time_threshold:

Answer (score 1):

Your database field `last_update` is datetime field and you are comparing it against date hence the error, Instead of `datetime.date.today()` use `datetime.datetime.now()`. Better use `django.utils.timezone` which will respect the `TIME_ZONE` in settings:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def is_old(self):
    """
    Is older than 6 months (since last update)
    """
    time_threshold = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(6*365/12)
    return bool(self.last_update > time_threshold)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the external module `dateutil`:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def is_old(last_update):
    time_threshold = date.today() - relativedelta(months=6)
    return last_update < time_threshold
```

That's assuming the type of `last_update` is a `date` object